# How to use a variable in your function from another function (Combination Calculator)

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am new in JS and I'm having difficulty with using a variable from another function to my new function.

the goal is to compute for a combination (combination calculator) but when I use this script code I don't get an output.

```js
var i, num, num2;

function factor() {
  x = 1;
  y = 1;
  num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    x = x * i;
  }
  i = i - 1;
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "The factorial of the number " + i + " is: " + x;
  num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  for (i = 1; i <= num2; i++) {
    y = y * i;
  }
  i = i - 1;
  document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = "The factorial of the number " + i + " is: " + y;
}

function partTwo() {
  a = y.factor(num - num2);
  b = x.factor / a;
  document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = "Answer: ";
}
```

```html
<!--Input-->
<h2 id="one"> Please enter first value for combination calculation </h2>
<input type="number" placeholder="Number 1" id="num"> <br> <br>
<!--Input 2-->
<h2 id="two"> Please enter second value for combination calculation </h2>
<input type="number" placeholder="Number 2" id="num2"> <br> <br>

<!--button-->
<button onclick="factor()"> ENTER </button>
<h2 id="res"> </h2>
<h2 id="res2"> </h2>

<button onclick="partTwo()"> CALCULATE </button>
<h2 id="res3"> </h2>
```

I was supposed to get an output for a combination calculator and need help how to do the second function

Comment: There are some things that are missing here. First of all, what is your expected output after clicking "CALCULATE"? What is `a = y.factor(num - num2);` supposed to do? Also, you have variables `a` and `b` in your `partTwo` function but it is not being used anywhere in the function.

Comment: You don't have an output right now because of the error `y.factor is not a function` but even if you get to resolve that, you will still not have any output, because you didn't output anything

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the variables out of their scope or if you want to use this variable
pass through the parameter
try this:

```
    var i, num, num2;

function factor() {
  x = 1;
  y = 1;
  num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  for(i = 1; i <= num; i++)  
    {
      x = x * i;
    }
    i = i - 1;  
    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "The factorial of the number " + i + " is: " + x ;

  num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  for(i = 1; i <= num2; i++)  
    {
      y = y * i;
    }
    i = i - 1;  
    document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = "The factorial of the number " + i + " is: " + y ;
    partTwo(x,y)
  
  }

  function partTwo (x,y) {
    
    a = y.factor(num - num2);
    b = x.factor/a;

    document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = "Answer: " ;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use variables from one function to another if you're going to make it a global variable.

But based on the format of your `partTwo()` function, I believe what you want to learn here is the use of "class" in JavaScript.

I reconstructed your code and changed a few stuff in your HTML and JavaScript.

```
<h2 id="one"> Please enter first value for combination calculation </h2> 
<input type="number" placeholder="Number 1" id="num1"> <br> <br>
<!--Input 2-->
<h2 id="two"> Please enter second value for combination calculation </h2>
<input type="number" placeholder="Number 2" id="num2"> <br> <br>
<!--These buttons were replaced by ID so that I can add an event listener in the JS instead of onclick tag-->
<button id="enter"> ENTER </button>  
<h2 id="res"> </h2>
<h2 id="res2"> </h2>
<button id="calculate"> CALCULATE </button>
<h2 id="res3"> </h2>
```

Here's the JS code using `class` instead of `function`:

```
class myfactor {
  constructor(num1, num2) {
    this.num1 = num1;
    this.num2 = num2;
  }
  x() {
    var xval = 1;
    for(var i = 1; i <= this.num1; i++)  
    {
      xval = xval * i;
    }
    i = i - 1;
    return xval;
  }
  
  y() {
    var yval = 1;
    for(var i = 1; i <= this.num2; i++){
      yval = yval * i;
    }
    i = i - 1;
    return yval;
  }
}
```

And here's the rest of the code, wherein you can find the "click" events for both "enter" and "calculate" button:

```
var factor;
var num1;
var num2;

document.getElementById("enter").addEventListener("click", function(){
  num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  
  factor = new myfactor(num1, num2);
  
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = "The factorial of the number " + num1 + " is: " + factor.x();
  document.getElementById("res2").innerHTML = "The factorial of the number " + num2 + " is: " + factor.y();
});

document.getElementById("calculate").addEventListener("click", function(){
  var a = factor.y() * (num1 - num2);
  var b = factor.x() / a;
  document.getElementById("res3").innerHTML = "Answer: " + b;
});
```

It is unclear in your question what you are trying to output here, but I just used your variable `b` as the final output since it has the last formula in the code.